# I want to handle dateTime null value in JSON parsing in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I need help handling the null values for DateTime JSON parse. Since some of the data does not have `createDate`, I have a problem showing the data
this is my code:

```
factory OfaModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TestModel(
    createdDate: DateTime.parse(json["CreatedDate"]),
    recordtypeBm: json["recordtype_bm"],
    amsCustodialHistoryBm: List<String>.from(json["AMSCustodialHistoryBM"].map((x) => x)),
    subjectCode: json["SubjectCode"]
    recordtypeBi: json["recordtype_bi"],
  );
```

Comment: If you're okay with mapping malformed dates to `null` instead of throwing an exception, you could use `DateTime.tryParse(json['CreatedDate'] ?? '')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make a condition like that:

```
json["CreatedDate"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["CreatedDate"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **DateTime.tryParse()**

```
createdDate : DateTime.tryParse(json["CreatedDate"]),
//DateTime.parse('') -> Returns (Uncaught Error: FormatException: Invalid date format)
//DateTime.tryParse('') -> Returns null instead of Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

just check if it's not or not,

```
factory OfaModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TestModel(
    createdDate:json["CreatedDate"] != null ? DateTime.parse(json["CreatedDate"]) : null,
    recordtypeBm: json["recordtype_bm"],
    amsCustodialHistoryBm: List<String>.from(json["AMSCustodialHistoryBM"].map((x) => x)),
    subjectCode: json["SubjectCode"]
    recordtypeBi: json["recordtype_bi"],
  );
```